# No decimals showing after comma ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

With a `$http.post` I get back a list of elements (to use in an ng-repeat) with a decimal in it (24.5 for example). When I look in the network inspector of the browser I see the element with 24.5, but in my front-end it shows only 24.

I tried to solve this: `{{node.status | number : 1}}`, but I get 24.0 and not 24.5 in that situation.

```
 $http.post('Client_Home/getZoneNodes', zone)
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.pData = response.data;
                    pData = response.data;
                    for (i = 0; i < pData.length; i++) {
                        pData[i].status = parseInt(pData[i].status);
                    }
                    $scope.zoneNodes = pData;
                });
```

I guess I create the problem myself with this function, because I parse an Int and not to a Double/Float ? Problem is that i need the int for some status in the ng-repeat and sometimes I need a Float/Double

Comment: We can't debug code you haven't shown us.  Share an MCVE please.

Comment: unclear question.Give some more details

Comment: have you tried to use `number.toFixed(2)` ?

Comment: Sorry guys, tried to show the part of code generating the issue... It's the parseInt, but I need sometimes int and sometimes double in the ng-repeat...

Comment: you should use `parseFloat()`  instead `parseInt()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line, `parseInt` to `parseFloat`

```
pData[i].status = parseFloat(pData[i].status);
```